# Set SSH Host IP Address on Rackspace for Ansible

Tags: ansible, rackspace-cloud, openstack-nova, pyrax, novaclient

#### The Question

When using the `rax` module to spin up servers and get inventory, how do I tell Ansible to connect to the IP address on an isolated network rather than the server's public IP?

Note: Ansible is being run from a server on the same isolated network.

#### The Problem

I spin up a server in the Rackspace Cloud using Ansible with the `rax` module, and I add it to an isolated/private network. I then add it to inventory and begin configuring it. The first thing I do is lock down SSH, in part by telling it to bind only to the IP address given to the host on the isolated network. The catch is, that means ansible can't connect over the public IP address, so I also set `ansible_ssh_host` to the private IP. (This happens when I add the host to inventory.)

```
- name: Add servers to group
  local_action:
    module: add_host
    hostname: "{{ item.name }}"
    ansible_ssh_host: "{{ item.rax.addresses.my_network_name[0].addr }}"
    groups: launched
  with_items: rax_response.success
  when: rax_response.action = 'create'
```

This works just fine on that first run of creating and configuring new instances. Unfortunately, the next time I try to connect to these servers, the connection is refused because Ansible is trying at an IP address on which SSH isn't listening. This happens because:

1. Ansible tries to connect to `ansible_ssh_host`...
2. But the `rax.py` inventory script has set `ansible_ssh_host` to the `accessIPv4` returned by Rackspace...
3. And Rackspace has set `accessIPv4` to the public IP address of the server.

Now, I'm not sure what to do about this. Rackspace does allow an [API call](http://docs.rackspace.com/servers/api/v2/cs-devguide/content/ServerUpdate.html) to update a server and set its `accessIPv4`, so I thought I could run another `local_action` after creating the server to do that. Unfortunately, the [rax](http://docs.ansible.com/rax_module.html) module doesn't appear to allow updating a server, and even if it did it depends on [pyrax](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax) which in turn depends on [novaclient](https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient), and [novaclient only allows updating the name of the server](https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/blob/b21d6775685fc2ca9bd5c13e817343789d7ad6c5/novaclient/v1_1/servers.py#L48), not `accessIPv4`.

Surely someone has done this before. What is the right way to tell Ansible to connect on the isolated network when getting dynamic inventory via the `rax` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually edit the ***rax.py*** file and change **line 125** and **line 163** from:

```
hostvars['ansible_ssh_host'] = server.accessIPv4
```

to:

```
hostvars['ansible_ssh_host'] = server.addresses['private'][0]['addr']
```

This should make the value of ansible_ssh_host the private IP.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing already, but it seems kinda hackish. (Though I appear to have a different version of rax.py--different lines and slightly different syntax.) I'll wait a bit and see if anyone else has ideas, otherwise I'll accept yours since it does solve the immediate problem. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it hackish. I would say it's more of a case of the Rackspace dynamic inventory file not being as full featured as some of the other dynamic inventory files. For Example, the AWS dynamic inventory file  has a settings file that lets you switch between using private IPs and public IPs.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought on this is to treat it like you have a tunnel you need to set up.

When you use the `rax` module, it [creates a group called "raxhosts"](http://docs.ansible.com/guide_rax.html#provisioning). By default, these are accessed using that public ipv4 address.

You could create another group using that group (via [`add_host`](http://docs.ansible.com/add_host_module.html)), but specify the IP you want to actually access it through.

```
- name: Redirect to raxprivhosts
  local_action:
      module: add_host
      hostname: "{{ item.name }}"
      ansible_ssh_host: "{{ item.rax_addresses['private'][0]['addr'] }}"
      ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ item.rax_adminpass }}"
      groupname: raxprivhosts
  with_items: raxhosts
```

Then apply playbooks against those groups as your follow on actions.

Let me know how this works out for you, I'm just throwing it out as an alternate to changing your rax.py manually.

Comment: Hmm, that's not a bad idea. I don't believe the "raxhosts" group is created automatically (it's just an example they give of how to use "add_host"), but maybe I could do the same thing with "all"? So I'd essentially be taking what I was doing just for newly created hosts and instead doing it for all of them.... But then I guess I'd have to do all my inventory and grouping by reading the servers' metadata myself instead of letting rax.py do it. (I think hosts in groups detected by rax.py would still have the wrong IP.) I'll give it some thought and then try it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I don't have something completely elegant. That was just off the top of my head from reading the docs a while back (and reading them again now).

Comment: But thank you! For now I think I'll just go with bkan's solution to avoid doing more of the inventory work in my playbooks, but that was very helpful to think through.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable in /etc/tower/settings.py to use the private network. It would either be

```
AWX_TASK_ENV['RAX_ACCESS_NETWORK'] = 'YOURNETWORK'
```

or

```
AWX_TASK_ENV['RAX_ACCESS_NETWORK'] = 'private'
```

You would then restart services afterwards with `ansible-tower-service restart`
You then need to refresh the inventory which you can do through the Tower interface. You'll now see that the host IP is set to the network you specified in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of ansible you need to change:

```
hostvars['ansible_ssh_host'] = server.accessIPv4
```

to:

```
hostvars['ansible_ssh_host'] = server.addresses['private'][0]['addr']
```

**AND**

```
hostvars[server.name]['ansible_ssh_host'] = server.accessIPv4
```

to:

```
hostvars[server.name]['ansible_ssh_host'] = server.addresses['private'][0]['addr']
```